# Flutter - Serializing a Java Pojo to Dart object

Tags: java, flutter, dart

I am using a method channel to call platform specific code in Flutter. (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=ios-channel-swift-tab#step-3-add-an-android-platform-specific-implementation)

In my MainActivity.java file, i have

```
String methodCall = call.method;
  switch (methodCall) {
      case "getUser":
         User user = new User();
         user.setAccessToken("eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1Ni");
         user.setUserId("randomName123");
         user.setLocation("USA");
         Log.d("configureFlutterEngine", "Got a user: " + user.toString());
         result.success(user);
         break;
```

user is an instance of User (All properties are Strings)

```
public class User {
   private String accessToken;
   private String userId;
   private String location
```

result.success(user) returns the an instance of User.

In my `/lib/main.dart` file I call the getUser method, which route to my Java class.

```
  /// Signs a user out
  Future<void> _getUser() async {
    User user;
    try {
      user = await platform.invokeMethod('getUser');
      print("getUser button was pressed");
      setState(() {
        _user = user;
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Failed: '${e.message}'.");
    }
  }
```

the User class in Dart is:

```
class User {
  String accessToken;
  String userId;
  String location;
```

However whenever I run my code, I get:

```
2020-01-21 13:37:55.065 12149-12149/com.package.name.sample E/MethodChannel#com.package.name/UserSignOn: Failed to handle method call
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported value:
    Access Token: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1Ni
    User ID: randomName123 
    Location: USA
```

As a note: If I return a simple string, and not the User object, this works fine, so I'm thinking it's something to do with serializing and deserializing the POJO to a Dart Object

Comment: Is there any progress on this issue?

Answer (score 3):

From the [Flutter documentation on platform channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels#codec), the list of supported Dart types that can be passed to a method channel (and their Java equivalents) are the following:

- **Dart Type: *Java Type***
- `null`: *null*
- `bool`: *java.lang.Boolean*
- `int`: *java.lang.Integer*
- `int`: *java.lang.Long* (if 32 bits are not enough)
- `double`: *java.lang.Double*
- `String`: *java.lang.String*
- `Uint8List`: *byte[]*
- `Int32List`: *int[]*
- `Int64List`: *long[]*
- `Float64List`: *double[]*
- `List`: *java.util.ArrayList*
- `Map`: *java.util.HashMap*

As you can see, you can't send raw Java Pojos across the method channel. Any data needs to be serialized to one of these types. For a Pojo, serializing it to a `HashMap` would probably be the most straight-forward.